# Keras: How to connect a CNN model with a decision tree

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I want to train a model to predict one's emotion from the physical signals. I have a physical signal and using it as input feature;

> ecg(Electrocardiography)

I want to use the CNN architecture to extract features from the data, and then use these extracted features to feed a classical **"Decision Tree Classifier"**. Below, you can see my CNN aproach without the decision tree;

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(15,60,padding='valid', activation='relu',input_shape=(18000,1), strides = 1,  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0.1, l2=0.1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2,data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv1D(30, 60, padding='valid', activation='relu',kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0.1, l2=0.1), strides=1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(4,data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))
```

I want to edit this code so that, in the output layer there will be working **decision tree** instead of `model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))`. I have tried to save the outputs of the last convolutional layer like this;

```
output = model.layers[-6].output
```

And when I printed out the `output` variable, result was this;

> THE OUTPUT:  Tensor("conv1d_56/Relu:0", shape=(?, 8971, 30),
>   dtype=float32)

I guess, the `output` variable holds the extracted features. Now, how can I feed my **decision tree** classifier model  with this data which is stored in the `output` variable? Here is the decision tree from scikit learn;

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = 'entropy')
dtc.fit()
```

How should I feed the `fit()` method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you doing supervised classification ? Do you want to train your DL model and decision tree jointly (this is not possible...)? One thing you can do is train your DL model with a FC layer, and then replace it a decision tree...

Comment: @ma3oun, yes it is a supervised classification. I want CNN model to extract features from my data and then I am going to use these extracted features to feed a decision tree model.

Comment: One way of doing this is adding some FC layers and train your network, then use your trained network to extract features and feed them into a decision tree (thus replacing the FC layers). Another way is to train an autoencoder to extract features and then to use the contracted data vector as input to your decision tree...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract a vector of features that you can pass on to another algorithm, you need a fully connected layer before your softmax layer. Something like this will add in a 128 dimensional layer just before your softmax layer:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(15,60,padding='valid', activation='relu',input_shape=(18000,1), strides = 1,  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0.1, l2=0.1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2,data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv1D(30, 60, padding='valid', activation='relu',kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0.1, l2=0.1), strides=1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(4,data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))
```

If you then run `model.summary()` you can see the name of the layers:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_9 (Conv1D)            (None, 17941, 15)         915       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_9 (MaxPooling1 (None, 8970, 15)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_10 (Dropout)         (None, 8970, 15)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_9 (Batch (None, 8970, 15)          60        
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_10 (Conv1D)           (None, 8911, 30)          27030     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_10 (MaxPooling (None, 2227, 30)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_11 (Dropout)         (None, 2227, 30)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_10 (Batc (None, 2227, 30)          120       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_6 (Flatten)          (None, 66810)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 128)               8551808   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_12 (Dropout)         (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 387       
=================================================================
Total params: 8,580,320
Trainable params: 8,580,230
Non-trainable params: 90
_________________________________________________________________
```

Once your network has been trained you can create a new model where the output layer becomes 'dense_7' and it'll generate 128 dimensional feature vectors:

```
feature_vectors_model = Model(model.input, model.get_layer('dense_7').output)
dtc_features = feature_vectors_model.predict(your_X_data)  # fit your decision tree on this data
```

Comment: `your_X_data` means train_x ? Also, is that important how many epochs I am running?

Comment: Yes train_x, test_x etc. The new model used for generating features doesn’t need training as it’s using the weights already learned from fitting ‘model’. For the original model, it is a good idea to use a callback that ends training when the validation loss stops improving.

Comment: well I tried and it is obviously working. But I wanted to ask that, is that the best way of doing this? Let's say, in my `conv1d` node I am using *10 filters* and that is why there should be 10 features extracted. After that, I am applying a Fully Connected Layer with the dense of *128* and using it to feed my decision tree. So with that, I had 128 features instead of 10.